# Mysql same row copy-same table 120 times

Tags: php, mysql

Simple mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE  `users` (
 `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `name` TEXT NOT NULL ,
 `surname` text NOT NULL ,
 `city` text NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `id` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

And inserted like:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `surname`, `city`) VALUES (1,`rock`,`fixed`,`london`);
```

How can i enter same table detail of one row 100 times with different primary id?

Comment: Remove the `id` column and the corresponding value in your insert query. `INSERT INTO users (name, surname, city) VALUES ('rock','fixed','london');`

Comment: Ok,now how can i copy same row for 100 times,do i require to copy that data 100 times?or some short trick?

Comment: Loop it. `for($x=0; $x<100; $x++){ /* INSERT QUERY */ }`

Comment: @Purohit you want to add records 120 or 100 times? how is this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32347141/4323504

Comment: It is same what you answered @LuthandoLoot

Comment: In php using it not entering 100 times or 120 times as i require,it just enter 1 time row on each execution.I used code:<?php
*/here mysql ocnnection

for($x=0; $x<100; $x++)
{
     $sql =INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `surname`, `city`)   
     VALUES   (`rock`,`fixed`,`london`);

 } 

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>

Comment: @Purohit you are executing your query outside the loop that is why it adds one record, check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with php you can do it this way:

```
for($i=0; $i< 119; $i++)
{
     //execute your query here, do not include your id column
     INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `surname`, `city`)   
     VALUES   (`rock`,`fixed`,`london`);
 }
```

**OR**
You can also do it with a mysql store procedure like:

```
//Loop stored procedure

DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test$$
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
 DECLARE count INT DEFAULT 0;
 WHILE count < 119 DO
      INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `surname`, `city`)   
      VALUES   (`rock`,`fixed`,`london`);
   SET count = count + 1;
 END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

> execute the stored procedure

```
call test();
```

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS:**
Your code is not working because you are executing your query "outside" the loop, you code should look like this:

```
<?php 

*/here mysql connection 
for($x=0; $x<100; $x++) 
{ 
   $sql =INSERT INTO users (name, surname, city) 
          VALUES (rock,fixed,london); 
   $status = $conn->query($sql);
} 

if ($status) 
{  echo "New record created successfully"; }
else { echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; } 
$conn->close(); 
?>
```

Comment: Any way i used php type but in mysql it says: #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: In php using it not entering 100 times or 120 times as i require,it just enter 1 time row on each execution.I used code:<?php */here mysql ocnnection for($x=0; $x<100; $x++) { $sql =INSERT INTO users (name, surname, city) VALUES (rock,fixed,london); } if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) { echo "New record created successfully"; } else { echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; } $conn->close(); ?> –

Comment: @Purohit that is because you are executing the query outside the loop, move the `if statement` inside the loop

Comment: @Purohit check my edited answer, everything is working fine

Comment: Ok,@luthando loot and thanks for pretty much explaination.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
for ($i=0; $i<= 119; $i++){
      //exclude id and do auto increament and primary key
       $qry = "INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `surname`, `city`) VALUES (`rock`,`fixed`,`london`)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it as a single SQL statement with no loop:-

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `surname`, `city`) VALUES (1,`rock`,`fixed`,`london`);
SELECT NULL, `rock`, `fixed`, `london`
FROM
(
    SELECT 0 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) units
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 0 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11
) tens
```

The 2 sub queries just return ranges of numbers. With 10 in one and 12 in the other when cross joined they will return in total 120 rows. Those 120 rows are just your fixed values, but with NULL for the id which the auto increment will sort out into a unique value.

Note that you can do larger ranges like this. For example if you wanted to insert 653 rows (just a fairly random choice of number):-

```
SELECT NULL, `rock`, `fixed`, `london`
FROM
(
    SELECT 0 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) units
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 0 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 
) tens
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 0 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 
) hundreds
WHERE (units.aCnt + 10 * tens.aCnt + 100 * hundreds.aCnt) < 653
```

Or specifying the id field as the calculated value:-

```
SELECT 1 + units.aCnt + 10 * tens.aCnt + 100 * hundreds.aCnt, `rock`, `fixed`, `london`
FROM
(
    SELECT 0 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) units
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 0 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 
) tens
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 0 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 
) hundreds
WHERE (units.aCnt + 10 * tens.aCnt + 100 * hundreds.aCnt) < 653
```

Comment: This is likely to be substantially quicker than doing ~120 separate inserts from php.

Answer (score -1):

Since the `id` has the property `AUTO_INCREMENT` this should generate a unique ID every time you enter data.

So your insert string can be like this:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `surname`, `city`) VALUES (`rock`, `fixed`, `london`);
```

The `id` field will then auto-increment each time, giving you unique IDs

Comment: Ok,now how can i copy same row for 100 times,do i require to copy that data 100 times?or some short trick?

Comment: @LuthandoLoot's answer shows you how to do a `for` loop in PHP, inserting 100 rows

Comment: In php using it not entering 100 times or 120 times as i require,it just enter 1 time row on each execution.I used code:<?php */here mysql ocnnection for($x=0; $x<100; $x++) { $sql =INSERT INTO users (name, surname, city) VALUES (rock,fixed,london); } if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) { echo "New record created successfully"; } else { echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; } $conn->close(); ?> –

Answer (score -2):

Just Use this query:

```
INSERT INTO users ( name, surname, city) VALUES ('rock','fixed','london');
```